# Best way to compare lists to fields on a list of objects in Groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

So I have a list:

```
def list = [1,2,3,...]
```

And then I have a list of objects from the database:

```
def loo = findAllBySomeField()
```

And for each object in the list, if field A on that object doesn't match anything in the first list, then I want to add field B on the object to another list. What's the best way to do this without having a bunch of .each and .collect closures? I've looked into intersect() and removeAll() but it seems there's no clean and simple way to do this.

Also is there a findAllBySomeFieldNotInList()? It seems grails only has the InList dynamic method but no NotInList().

Comment: Have you tried using `findAllBySomeFieldNotInList()`? It should work because `Not` is like a binary operator that can be used in dynamic finders.

Comment: it says SomeFieldNot is not a property of the object. On grails [findAllBy](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) page there's only InList but there's no NotInList.

Comment: Your most efficient way is going to be to write an HQL, criteria or SQL query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
createCriteria().list() {
    not {
        inList 'someField', unwantedValues
    }
    projections {
        property 'fieldB' // or distinct instead of property
    }
}
```

should do